# (Discord.py) Send a dm or is to all members of all servers

Tags: discord, discord.py

I begin the dev for 2 days and i want to create a command in the dm of the bot ">

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('><dmall'):

        name = message.content.split(" ")[1]

        if(name == "all"):
            for member in message.guild.members:
                try:
                    await member.send("test")
                except discord.Forbidden:
                    print("[DM]" + name + "à bloqué ses dm")
        else:
            member = discord.utils.get(message.guild.members, name=name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: PLEASE DO NOT ABUSE THIS, IT IS A BANNABLE OFFENSE ON [DISCORD'S TOS](https://discord.com/terms)**

```py
# an alternative to putting your commands in an on_message event:
@bot.command()
async def dmall(ctx):
    for m in bot.get_all_members():
        await m.send("Hello! This is a DM :)")
    print("Done!")

# error handler
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.errors.Forbidden):
        print(f"[DM] {ctx.author} has DMs disabled.")
    else:
        print(error)
```

References:

- [`Client.get_all_members()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_all_members)
- [`discord.on_command_error()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.on_command_error)
- [Exceptions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#exception-hierarchy)